# Node require returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, require

I have an ErrorHandler class in my node code that handles all occuring errors.

Every Error has its own class. All classes are placed in seperate files so the folder structure is:

- ErrorHandler.js

  - Error110.js
  - Error131.js
  - ...

ErrorHandler requires each of these files (along with some others)

```
var serverErrorCodes        = require('../../config/ErrorCodesConfig').server,
clientErrorCodes            = require('../../config/ErrorCodesConfig').client,
Error110                    = require('./errors/Error110').Error110,
Error131                    = require('./errors/Error131').Error131,
Error132                    = require('./errors/Error132').Error132,
Error133                    = require('./errors/Error133').Error133,
Error150                    = require('./errors/Error150').Error150;
```

When checking in node-debugger during runtime, the require result ist:

```
Closure:
  Error110: function Error110(params)
  Error131: function Error131(params)
  Error132: undefined
  Error133: undefined
  Error150: function Error150(messageObject, callback)
```

Error132 and Error133 are not available after the require, while the others are perfectly.

I've read that this happens if you have a require cycle and thus a required module (A) is requiring a module (B) which again requires module A. Node then ends this cycle by returning `undefined` after the first require. This is not the case.

So my last guess is that, at the time of execution, due to the asynchronous nature of node, the files are "not yet" required and thus only "some" files get included. But require is a synchronous function. I am not certain if this scenario is possible and how I would check for it.

I am clueless here, help is much appreciated.

Best regards,
Worp

**Edit 1:**
As Travis Webb pointed out: This is wrong!
<s>It also happens if your require a module that is already included somewhere earlier in the code. I thought about this but I am not requiring a module. And over all this doesn't seem to be true, since, for example, the `util` module needs to be included in every file that it is used, instead of just once.</s>

Comment: Are you sure that the files inside are correct? What does console.log(require('./errors/Error132')) show? What are the contents of the Error132 and Error133 files?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 

I am pretty certaint he contents are correct. At least I have tried to copy/paste the contents of a working file into a failing file (changing the class names via find/replace, paying attention to what was getting replaced) and tried to require it with the same outcome.

Since I am currently travelling and don't have access to the code, I will post the failing files asap once I get back.

Comment: So! It's been a while. Sorry about that.
It turns out, you were right. A colleague of mine committed a patch that changed one number in each file, turning the export of Error133 to "Error132" and in Error133 to "Error132".

I am very sorry for this stupid mistake, I just didnt spot it...

Can you make your comment an answer, so I can mark it correct?

Comment: So do you want to mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Hey Travis =) I feel like your post is ultimately the more important one for the overall info contained in it. It was not the answer to this question though, as Jessie's answer actually got me to figuring it out. I feel like your answer below will continue to receive the attention it deserves and upvotes for it =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure that the files inside are correct? What does console.log(require('./errors/Error132')) show? What are the contents of the Error132 and Error133 files?

Answer (score 28):

A simpler explanation is that `module.exports` is resolving to `undefined` inside the module that you are requiring. Post the code of the failing modules.

> It also happens if your require a module that is already included somewhere earlier in the code.

This statement is incorrect.

> due to the asynchronous nature of node, the files are "not yet" required

`require` is synchronous.

It is correct that if module `A` requires `B`, which in turn requires `A`, then `A` will be `undefined` in module `B`. But I'm not sure this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will edit that in.

Since I am currently on the road for the next couple of days, I will post the code of the failing files asap when I am back home.

Comment: Hey Travis,
as you can read from my comment above, I was stupid and overlooked the typing error my colleague had brought in.

Nevertheless your point is very important, besides of me already editing it in my original post.

Since I don't have enough reputation yet to give points, is there anyhting I can do to mark your answer as important?

Comment: Continue using Stackoverflow :) I'm patient.

Comment: Still, thx a lot!
I will remember your comment. Only 5 reputation to go until I can upvote it :D

Comment: How about now? :)

Comment: Thanks @TravisWebb, this statement helps me to resolve my issue. 
>>t is correct that if module A requires B, which in turn requires A, then A will be undefined in module B. But I'm not sure this is the problem.

Comment: This man Travis really came back 5 years later to get that upvote. That's due diligence right there.